Expand list of struct column in `polars`
I have a pl.DataFrame with a column that is a list of struct entries. The lengths of the lists might differ:
pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3],
        "s": [
            [
                {"a": 1, "b": 1},
                {"a": 2, "b": 2},
                {"a": 3, "b": 3},
            ],
            [
                {"a": 10, "b": 10},
                {"a": 20, "b": 20},
                {"a": 30, "b": 30},
                {"a": 40, "b": 40},
            ],
            [
                {"a": 100, "b": 100},
                {"a": 200, "b": 200},
                {"a": 300, "b": 300},
                {"a": 400, "b": 400},
                {"a": 500, "b": 500},
            ],
        ],
    }
)

This looks like this:
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ s                               │
│ --- ┆ ---                             │
│ i64 ┆ list[struct[2]]                 │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}]           │
│ 2   ┆ [{10,10}, {20,20}, … {40,40}]   │
│ 3   ┆ [{100,100}, {200,200}, … {500,… │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

I've tried various versions of unnest and explode, but I am failing to turn this into a long pl.DataFrame where the list is turned into rows and the struct entries into columns. This is what I want to see:
pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
            "a": [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
            "b": [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
        }
    )

Which looks like this:
shape: (12, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 10  ┆ 10  │
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 20  │
│ …   ┆ …   ┆ …   │
│ 3   ┆ 100 ┆ 100 │
│ 3   ┆ 200 ┆ 200 │
│ 3   ┆ 300 ┆ 300 │
│ 3   ┆ 400 ┆ 400 │
│ 3   ┆ 500 ┆ 500 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

Is there a way to manipulate the first pl.DataFrame into the second pl.DataFrame?

depending on your end goal, it may be more performant to do the computation within the array, and avoid exploding

First explode, then unnest:
df.explode('s').unnest('s')

Output:
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 10  ┆ 10  │
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 20  │
│ …   ┆ …   ┆ …   │
│ 3   ┆ 100 ┆ 100 │
│ 3   ┆ 200 ┆ 200 │
│ 3   ┆ 300 ┆ 300 │
│ 3   ┆ 400 ┆ 400 │
│ 3   ┆ 500 ┆ 500 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘


This is it! I incorrectly tried to use unnest and explode inside with_columns instead of applying it to the pl.DataFrame.
